# css textAlign with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have trouble align text using innerHTML

```
a= document.createElement('a');
a.style.cssText= 'font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; text-align:center;';
a.innerHTML = 'Align ME TO CENTER!';
```

Default align to left, and it stuck that way... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is a bug in your code:

where you have

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.style.cssText= 'font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; text-align:center;';
a.innerHTML = 'Align ME TO CENTER!';
```

You should have:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('style','font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; text-align:center;');
a.innerHTML = 'Align ME TO CENTER!';
```

And to fix your problem, in the style, you need to set the `display` property to `block`, like so:

```
a.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; display:block;');
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have thought of using setAttribute.. I thought they do the same thing, but I guess not.